# ER_LOCK_DEADLOCK called when there is no lock

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql-error-1064, rds

Logs showing that from time to time this error is raised.

I'm reading the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html) and it's very confusing because we're not locking any tables to do inserts and we have no transactions beyond individual SQL calls.

So - might this be happening because we're running out of the mySQL connection pool in Node? (We've set it to something like 250 simultaneous connections).

I'm trying to figure out how to replicate this but having no luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every query not run within an *explicit* transaction runs in an *implicit* transaction that immediately commits when the query finishes or rolls back if an error occurs... so, yes, you're using transactions.

Deadlocks occur when at least two queries are in the process of acquiring locks, and each of them holds row-level locks that they happened to acquire in such an order that they each now need another lock that the other one holds -- so, they're "deadlocked."  An infinite wait condition exists between the running queries.  The server notices this.

The error is not so much a fault as it is the server saying, "I see what you did, there... and, you're welcome, I cleaned it up for you because otherwise, you would have waited forever."

What you aren't seeing is that there are two guilty parties -- two different queries that caused the problem -- but only one of them is punished.  The query that has accomplished the least amount of work (admittedly, this concept is nebulous) will be killed with the deadlock error, and the other query happily proceeds along its path, having no idea that it was the lucky survivor.

This is why the deadlock error message ends with "try restarting transaction" -- which, if you aren't explicitly using transacrions, just means "run your query again."

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-deadlocks.html and examine the output of `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;`, which will show you the other query -- the one that helped cause the deadlock but that was not killed -- as well as the one that was.

Comment: so is it safe to catch this error and just run the query again? Or is it better to spit it back to the API and re-submit the entire request that results in this query being made?

Comment: Retrying the query yourself, immediately... or later (by tossing an error back to the API and making the caller call again) should be equivalent from the database's perspective.

Comment: This is probably the best explanation for that error I could stumble on.